# DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type True/False with values of type Integer

Tags: dax

Hi I am looking to complete a vlookup to determine rate costs.  I have created a date calendar that contains bank holidays and created a relationship with my main data set. if a job was completed on a sunday or a bank holiday it would be rate 3 or if it mon-fri after 6pm and anytime saturday then rate 2 and all others rate 1. I have tried completing a vlookup howerver it show an error "DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type True/False with values of type Integer".  i am only learning power BI and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have columns that show start day, start hour and true/false if it is a bank holiday (Cant seem to add picture)

Comment: Please share the DAX code that is giving the error.

Comment: hi this is the code i used:

Comment: Rate = IF(or( [Act Start Day]="Sunday",'MWM - WO Data'[Started B/P Holiday] = TRUE()),"Rate 3",IF(AND('MWM - WO Data'[Act Start Day]<>"Sunday",'MWM - WO Data'[Actual Start Hr]<18>8),"Rate 2","Rate 1"))